# XML relative path Navigation

Tags: xml, selenium

For a software test I need to find out the ID or rather the specific integer of "parentid" of a div container. My first idea was to filter for the value "1" to get inside the correct div block. Since this is also a unique element, this works. However, now I am wondering what is the best way to navigate back relatively to the correct parent div block to get me the ID.

Can someone maybe help me here? below is also a picture for a better understanding.

best regards
Andreas

[image: Code Snipped]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make use of `ancestor` like below with `starts-with` method, there is not need to use `contains`, since we are just looking for `parentid`.

```
//*[@value='1']/ancestor::div[starts-with(@id,'parentid')]
```

In case you would like to have the entire `parentid`, please use this :

```
//*[@value='1']/ancestor::div[@id='parentid_593']
```

or in general you can write `/..` to go to parent node from current node. so

```
//*[@value='1']/../../../../..
```

should get the job done, but it looks brittle. Please use the first one.

[Reference link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)